# Converting DD-MM-YYYY to date format and setting value to html.Editor doesn't show value

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

String in DD-MM-YYYY when converted to date and passed into html.editor doesn't show the correct value.

```
@Html.Editor("StartDate", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date", @placeholder = " Start Date", @required = "", @id = "txtStrDate" } })
```

```
var myDate = document.querySelector(".update_ano #txtStrDate");

       var Displaydate = convertDateToRequiredFormat(strdate); // Converts date to DD-MM-YYYY
       var dateFormatted = new Date(Displaydate.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"));

       console.log(dateFormatted)//Shows the correct date format
       myDate.value = dateFormatted;
       console.log(myDate.value);// Shows empty Console
```

[Razor HTML.Editor shows DD/MM/YYYY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Iz1.png)

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector();` returns an html object which doesn't have a value property.

Try change `myDate.value = dateFormatted` to `myDate.innerText = dateFormatted`

PS. You could look into the [.toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) function to format the date as well.

Comment: The value appears when I used the innerText property. However the Razor html.editor style shows the vale as dd/mm/yyy and not the date passed into the element.

Comment: @ANB tried using `myDate.innerText = dateFormatted.toString()` ?